# Change password directly without Okta web console

Tags: okta, okta-api

Does Okta have an API to send “change password” URL to the user (or widget) ?

Okta has “change password” API.

https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#change-password

However, it requres oldPassword/newPassword as input parameters. It means that our system needs to temporarily store password on memory when I integrate Okta with our system. Due to the security reason, we would like to avoid storing password in our system and directly input password to Okta. Our user will not use Okta web console directly.

I found we can send “reset password” URL to the user.

https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#reset-password

However, it is not “change password” because user status is changed.

Can we have a good solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to update user with POST and send a new `credentials` object to update its password- https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#update-user

Comment: Thanks for replying.  

I also confirmed its api.
But, I would like to avoid also to temporarily store password on memory when I integrate Okta with our system.

The flow using the reset password API is very secure according to the rules of our organization because the password is entered on the screen of the Okta domain. (But, it is not “change password” because user status is changed.)

Comment: Another person said, "How about the Forgot Password operation with sendEmail set to true?", But it seemed different from what we wanted to do.

We would like to integrate Okta and our system while achieving a simple user password change flow via the Okta domain screen (or an alternative method).

Comment: Ah, my bad, I haven't fully read your original question... I don't believe there is a method of achieving